# Custom footer in WordPress with bootstrap 4+ code

Tags: html, wordpress, bootstrap-4, footer

Hey I am using a new theme that is not giving me any footer for display on any of the pages. It is a nulled theme in Wordpress. Can I add a custom HTML Bootstrap footer to all the pages. I want to add a footer with 5 columns:

1. Column 1 Logo and short about us below it.
2. Column 2 Quick links.
3. Column 3 wp-job-manager plugin updates.
4. Column 4 facebook posts.
5. Column 5 instagram gallery.

I searched over wordpress.org and google but could not find the custom code for this. Also, I want to include all the custom code in Bootstrap format. What I have to do to show it correctly can you please suggest?

Also I need the footer to be respoonsive.

The design for the footer is submitted as the image.[Footer Custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQpoo.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That is not how Stack Overflow, Wordpress.org or Google works - the exact answer to your specific requirements is unlikely to be out there because everyone has different requirements. Instead you will need to do some research and learn how to use the information that is available, and give it a go yourself. If you have specific questions, please give us the exact details and show us what you have got so far, as we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

inside of your [footer.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Footer_.28footer.php.29) file, add the following:

```php
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<footer><!-- the code for your five columns goes here --></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And then for each column, you don't want to hard code stuff in, so what is commonly done is to add separate widget areas for each column. See [How to Register a Widget Area](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes).

Comment: Shall I have also to include some Bootstrap files and what about Bootstrap 4+